# Trabalhando com Transform3d em jQuery

Tags: jquery, html5, css3

Estou tentando fazer uma função que aumente ou diminua o tamanho de um objeto. Para isso utilizo o `transform: scale`. Porém meu objeto já utiliza `transform: translated3d` para setar a posição do mesmo. Dessa maneira, o css fica da seguinte maneira:

```
transform: translate3d(-862px, 512px, 0px) scale(0.5, 5);
```

Porem ao determinar por jQuery um novo `scale`, ele substitui todo meu transform.
Como atualizar meu transform para uma nova scale sem que eu perca meu `translated 3d`?

Alguém tem alguma ideia?

Answer (score 0):

Podes fazer isso com JavaScript, por segurança (para funcionar em browsers diferentes) usa os prefixos de CSS necessários:

```
div.style.webkitTransform = transfromString;
div.style.MozTransform = transfromString;
div.style.msTransform = transfromString;
div.style.OTransform = transfromString;
div.style.transform = transfromString;
```

Um exemplo poderia ser assim:

```js
function zoom(x, y) {
    return `scale(${x}, ${y}) translate3d(${x}px, 100px, ${x}px) `;  
}

let x = 0,
    y = 0;
const div = document.querySelector('div');

function mudarZoom() {
    x += 0.1;
    y += 0.15;
    if (y > 5) return;
    const transfromString = zoom(x, y);
    div.style.webkitTransform = transfromString;
    div.style.MozTransform = transfromString;
    div.style.msTransform = transfromString;
    div.style.OTransform = transfromString;
    div.style.transform = transfromString;
    setTimeout(mudarZoom, 200);
}

mudarZoom();
```

```css
div {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #aaf;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    transition: transform 1s;
}
```

```html
<div>X</div>
```